# Rewrites is not working for external root URL

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting

next.config.js
We have added below code on next.config.js file. When we test, it's redirecting on  stackoverflow website.

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
        source: "/test",
        destination: `https://stackoverflow.com/`,
        },
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct.

It's most likely a browser cache setting, since you probably tried using `redirects()` it cached the redirect.

Try opening in a different browser or in incognito mode.